# Mapping Lists and writing into Excel using groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui

I am new to groovy. I need to run all cases in my testSuite and update excel sheet with pass or fail status and the assertion due to which it has failed.

I have managed to get the testcase name , pass/fail status , assertion name in a list.

Eg : [TestCase2,TestCase1,TestCase3] [PASS,FAIL,PASS] [NA,XpathMismatch,NA]

Expected Excel sheet Op

```
**CaseName**       **Status**  **Log**
TestCase1            FAIL       XpathMismatch
TestCase2            PASS       NA
TestCase3            PASS       NA
```

Initially My sheet has only the testcase name Column. Other 2 columns **Status** and **Log** needs to be updated from the List.
Another problem faced is My list is not ordered, ie My excel has the cases in the order TC1,TC2,TC3 but my list has in some other order.

Kindly help or advice on how to program this in groovy in soapUI.
I am using POI jar

Comment: Using Excel sounds horrible.  Consider using Spock Data Tables https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

Comment: This sounds very painful! SoapUI can generate a JUnit-style report. There are various tools that can convert that into Excel, or something else.

Comment: I completely understand , but this was my clients expectation ! Stuck up very badly they are not okay with TestNG report as well